# Applications of the Clifford algebra in machine learning and statistics?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, clifford-algebras

I recently came across this article, "[Geometric algebra and computer graphics](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3305366.3328099)" and started wondering whether there are interesting applications of Clifford/Geometric algebra to statistics and machine learning.

Any pointers are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I would say your question needs more context in that I would like to know why you expect applications to statistics and/or machine learning. If possible, what specific aspects of statistics and/or machine learning do you think have a chance to be related and why?

Comment: Thanks @MarkS. I ask because geometry shows up everywhere in machine learning and statistics, for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_geometry. And algebras are useful for manipulating objects at a higher level of abstraction. So it would be nice to know if there exists work at the intersection of these disciplines.

Comment: I was unfamiliar with "information geometry", so maybe someone is doing the work you're looking for. But I would say that geometric algebra is not really the intersection of (differential?) geometry and (universal?) algebra - more like a fringe alternate way of writing certain things in linear algebra and differential geometry that is more convenient in some cases and arguably more elegant at times.

Answer (score 2):

Adaptive filtering is one of the building blocks of machine learning and AI. There’s a paper by the author of OpenGA, CTO and co-founder of upstride.io on the matter: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.03450.pdf